# Java player_width and player_height errors

Tags: java

I am trying to make this game, and right now, I have a character that can move around, but I want to efficiently change the width and height of the character. So the sizes for the character going up and down are different from the sizes for the character going left and right, so I made this if statement where if the player is going up, then the width is this and if the player is going right, then the with is that. But when I finish typing out the code, it gives me two errors:

```
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
```

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong?

Here's the code:

```
public class player extends creature {
    // other code

    private static int player_width;
    private static int player_height = 70; // error 1 here

    if(currentimage == assets.player_up) {
        player_width = 50;
    } else if(currentimage == assets.player_down) {
        player_width = 50;
    } else if(currentimage == assets.player_right) {
        player_width = 60;
    } else if(currentimage == assets.player_left) {
        player_width = 60;
    } // error 2 here

    public player(game game, float x, float y) {
        super(x, y,player_width,player_height);
        this.game = game;

    }
```

Here's the creature constructor:

```
public abstract class creature extends entity {

public static final int DEFAULT_HEALTH = 10;
public static final float DEFAULT_SPEED = 3.0f;
public static final int DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH = 64,
        DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT = 64;

protected int health;
protected float speed;
protected float xMove, yMove;

public creature(float x, float y, int width, int height) {
    super(x, y, width, height);
    health = DEFAULT_HEALTH;
    speed = DEFAULT_SPEED;
    xMove = 0;
    yMove = 0;

}
```

Comment: Wheres the method? Are those class scoped variables? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, you should put those if statements in your constructor. They won't run if they're inside a class but not a method.Just put them in your

```
public player(game game, float x, float y)
```

method, and you should be golden.

Note: just a sidenote, you should capitalize class name, it makes for easier to read code.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Comment: I'm glad. Please upvote my answer if it helped you out.Thanks.

Comment: There was actually another error. It said that the constructor call must be in the beginning of the constructor. If I move it to the beginning of the constructor, then player_width and player_height would not be defined.

Comment: Why are you passing player_width with your call to super? It would be helpful to see the creature constructor, since I don't know what calculations are being done.